# Infragistics wingrid

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using a infragistics ultrawingrid and am trying to use formula in one of my columns. I have used many formulas and they all work but now I am running into an issue when the actual column name would be something like bla bla bla (Y or N) so my formula would look like the following:

```
e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("Tax").Formula = "IF([Includes Tax (Y or N)]<>'Y',[Unit Price]*0.0825,0)"
```

and I get an error - I would guess it would be the () in the formula - how do I use these in a formula?

Comment: `and I get an error` - which error do you get?

Comment: When I use the Column name [Includes Tax (Y or N)] I get a #REF! error. If I name the Column [Includes Tax] it works fine no #REF! error. I have to use the "(Y or N)" in the name of the column

Answer (score 0):

You are getting #REF! error because the CalcManager tries to evaluate incorrectly the text inside the parentheses "()".

More information about the usage of the Formulas could be found at the [Formula Syntax](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wincalcmanager-formula-and-reference-guide) paragraph.

In your case since parentheses are part of the name of your column you would have to escape them, so that way, the CalcManager won't try to evaluate them anymore, and you can do that by using the following way to set your Formula instead:

```
e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("Tax").Formula = "IF([Includes Tax \\(Y or N\\)]<>'Y',[Unit Price]*0.0825,0)"
```